# Best way to transmit sqlite data to a web server from an Android Unit?

Tags: android, sqlite

The title almost says it all.

I'm building an Android App to collect data on sites. The data is stored in a sqlite database on the unit.

I'd like to transmit them to a web server over wifi. 
The data is to be stored in sql form and analysed on the web server, then graphed on a web page.

I though about making a csv and send it to a php page that would parse it and write it to the server sql database.
I saw alson json, but must read more about it.

What are the best options to have the data transfered with integrity ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using JSON for a couple reasons:

1. It is human readable.
2. There are nice libraries for JSON-Object Mapping, such as [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) or [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).
3. There are `JSONObject`/`JSONArray` classes that are a part of Android that are easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

As an additional option you can use Google's [protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/).  With protobuf you have to include an additional library and write your data in a specific message format, but you gain an automatically generated library with getter/setter methods *and* the data is sent in binary form.  All you have to do on either end is send/receive the number of bytes of the message and then write/read the message itself; the library takes care of populating all of your instance variables.

Of course this depends on what language you are using on the server, as you have to use a protobuf library there as well; but it would appear that there are [many different language bindings](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns), including for PHP.

Comment: I checked the protocol buffers. Looks nice but may be too heavy for my app.